# How to improve Aruco Marker Pose Estimation?

Tags: computer-vision, aruco, pose-estimation

I'm having a hard time estimating the positions of the Aruco markers with the camera. In my tests with the DICT_6X6_250 dictionary and the board with 4 markers of 20x20 cm on it, I measured at 6 meters with an error of 20-30 cm. I need more precise measurements.

Is this error rate normal? What can I do to increase accuracy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general there are ambiguity issues with Aruco, which you can find [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/8813).

I am doing abit of research on Fiducial Markers and this error rate is pretty normal. The Pose estimation of the markers tend to have errors in x and y rotation and z Translation.

However, there are some factors that can influence the accuracy of Aruco Pose estimation. Here are some points, that can help improve Pose estimation accuracy, which you should take into consideration:

- The first is to use a Camara with a high resolution. If the Marker is small in the image plane the pose estimation will not be as accurate.
- Secondly instead of using `cv2.aruco.estimatePoseSingleMarkers()`
  I would recommend using `cv2.SolvePnP()` as it allows you to use different Perspective N Point algorithms to calculate the Pose. You can read more about SolvePnP [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d5/d1f/calib3d_solvePnP.html) and the different methods [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga357634492a94efe8858d0ce1509da869)
- For the Aruco Detection `cv2.detectMarkers()` use a SubPixel Corner refinement method.
- Lastly you can use a Pose Refinement Method to improve the estimated pose ([here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d5/d1f/calib3d_solvePnP.html#:%7E:text=Pose%20refinement%20consists%20in%20estimating,solvePnPRefineVVS()%20for%20this%20problem.)). This method reduces the reprojection error of the estimated Pose and as a result you should get better Pose estimation accuracy.

Answer (score 3):

Inaccuracies of *pose* can stem from inaccuracies in *subpixel localization*.

Almost all algorithms for subpixel localization, and all people, assume a *linear* relationship between what's physically there (edges, corners) and how that is mapped to pixel intensities.

Webcams<sup>1</sup> give gamma-compressed data, not raw linear sensor values. Also, webcams *love* to "sharpen" the picture. Both affect subpixel localization.

I would *not* recommend a subpixel refinement method that works on the pixels of the *corners themselves*. For the aforementioned reasons, that's worse than going by the *edges* of the marker, and intersecting those to *get* corners. This supposes that lens distortion is reasonable. If it isn't, and your lens calibration isn't absolutely solid... then you *would* do better to work with corners rather than calculate them from edges.

---

<sup>1</sup> Not unique to webcams. That goes for *everything* that isn't a "raw sensor" file format. All JPEG, PNG, ... images are gamma-compressed, and so are all videos.